# qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: gnome, snap, qt

I have this problem where i can't run a snap app
my system is a dualbooted DELL Latitude E7450, 8 GB ram, 2.5 GHz Intel i5,
250 GB SSD, running Zorin  core 15 (170 GB) and windows 10 (80 GB)

my problem is that the snap app "noson" won't run and when i do it from the terminal i just get 
'''

```
$snap run noson
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory
 realpath: '': No such file or directory

 qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
 Could not connect to any X display.
```

I searched around and couldnt find anything that did the trick